# Nested reference object is persisting as null

Tags: java, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to store below pojo in couchbase with spring-data, but persist json is storing "user field of type User" as null.

```
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Document
public class ProjectXYZ {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String prjname;

    @Field
    private User user;

    //setter and getter

}
```

Update:
User Pojo

```
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Document
public class User {

    @Id
    @Field
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String email;

    @Field
    private String firstName;

    @Field
    private String lastName;

    //setter and getter
}
```

And as below I am saving it, All works fine and as expected but User object get stored as null.

```
    ProjectXYZ project = new ProjectXYZ();
    project.setUser(getUser(request));
    project = projectXYZService.createProject(project);
```

Comment: How are you expecting `User` to be stored? Please post code for class `User`

Comment: I think @ManyToOne should be used for user

Comment: do you have any example, as it is in spring-data-couchbase?

Comment: When you debug, does the `project` object have the `user` field set correctly before saving?

Comment: @Madhu Bhat, Yes on debug I can see the user object with its value..But it store as blank..And on retrieving it fetches object with all property null..

Answer (score 1):

References are not directly supported through Spring data couchbase as it needs to store meta information about the reference document id.

However there is support for fetching associated entities through N1QL ANSI Joins available in current Lovelace (3.1.x) versions. Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blob/6aadcfcc60eadf75778ab25d78a3eaecf4c67ce6/src/main/asciidoc/ansijoins.adoc) for it.